# ncat v7.6 UDP -k and -w not working as expected

Tags: netcat, udp, nc

At work ( BSD nc version ) and on many internet examples ncat can listen to udp and be used with the following options :

1. `-k` which allows multiple connections
2. `-w 0` which terminates the current connection when the client disconnects

At home I have the following

Command : Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
OS : Fedora 27

I am unable to use either `-k` or `-w 0`.

```
ncat -klu localhost 8000
Ncat: UDP mode does not support the -k or --keep-open options, except with --exec or --sh-exec. QUITTING.

nc -luw 0 localhost 8000
Ncat: Invalid -w timeout (must be greater than 0). QUITTING.
```

How do I do the keep alive and the instant timeout in my version of ncat? ( man page does not help )

Thanks

Comment: What's your question? Why don't you do check with the package manager on your system at work what version (and flavor) your ncat is?

Comment: It seems there has been considerable change in 7.6. How can I achieve the equivalent of using -k and -w 0 in my version?

Answer (score 3):

First, nc,ncat, and netcat are all technically different tools that play on each other's name, but thus don't necessarily provide the exact same (interoperable) features/options.

Second, it's not clear what version is being used at work, but in current versions of ncat, the option k is not usable for udp. It only works with tcp. But ncat will keep listening even on udp, even if the source disconnects, because udp is stateless (there is no connection process). But it won't recieve any more packets unless the source re"connects"/resends from the same source port it used the first time (because latest versions of ncat lock on to the first source port they see on udp, and then ignore all others until the command/listen is restarted. This behavior is unfortunately not configurable, unless you modify the source code). Hence the only "workaround" would be to look for another tool, or code your own in python. Here's an alternate I use and coded myself:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from socket import socket,AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,SO_REUSEADDR,SOL_SOCKET
from time import sleep,ctime
import sys

if len(sys.argv)>2:
    localIP = sys.argv[1]
    localPort = int(sys.argv[2])
else:
    print("Space-separated IP and Port are required")
    exit()

print(f"listening on {localIP}:{localPort}")
bufSize = 1500

sock = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((localIP, localPort))

while True:
    message, ipport = sock.recvfrom(bufSize)
    print(ctime(), f"[{ipport[0]}:{ipport[1]}]",str(message)[2:-1])
```

It's not the simplest it can be, but it also prints the timestamp and ip and port from which each individual packet came from. Place it in a file with a ".py" extension, and type it directly as a command to execute it (assuming you have python correctly setup), and pass it the IP and ports to bind on (space separated). The IP can be something like "0.0.0.0" or "127.0.0.1" or even "localhost" to bind to any or localhost interfaces (don't include the quotes). If you don't want timestamps or remote ip/port, leave out their corresponding parameters on the last line to the print function. For example, to get only the message, replace the last line with:

```
print(str(message)[2:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages give you a pretty good idea of what needs to be done

---

```
ncat -klu localhost 8000
Ncat: UDP mode does not support the -k or --keep-open options, except with --exec or --sh-exec. QUITTING.
```

You have to provide a listening program for `ncat` to use. To have the input just echo back to the sender, you can do this:

```
ncat -e /bin/cat -klu localhost 8000
```

---

```
nc -luw 0 localhost 8000
Ncat: Invalid -w timeout (must be greater than 0). QUITTING.
```

`nc` doesn't support a zero wait time, so just use something else

```
nc -luw 1 localhost 8000
```

Unfortunately, nc does not support subsecond wait times, but you can use the more feature rich `ncat` instead:

```
ncat -lu -w 100ms localhost 8000
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers do provide valuable information on how to work around this problem. To synthesize it all into a good work-around using ncat, here's a bash one-liner to accomplish a (nearly) instantly re-usable UDP listener:

```
while [ /bin/true ]; do ncat -i 1ms -u -l 127.0.0.1 8000 2>/dev/null; done
```

Just running ncat by itself with those parameters will accept a single UDP packet and then quit 1 millisecond after the packet is received, reporting on stderr that it's quitting. Redirecting stderr to /dev/null suppresses the timeout message. Wrapping the whole thing in a infinite while loop will allow it to (nearly) instantly re-listen when a UDP packet has been received.